# get interactive input using glib functions in C

Tags: c, glib

I am writing a c library but before I want to test the functions. So, I do the following:

```
int main(void)
{
GString *msg = NULL;
msg = g_string_sized_new(256);
printf ("Insert a string (255 characters at most): ");
do_fgets((char *) msg->str, (size_t) msg->len, stdin);
printf("msg->allocated_len = %u \n", (size_t) msg->allocated_len);
printf("msg->len = %u \n", (size_t) msg->len);

return 0;
}
```

the compile is ok, but the program prints the following:
msg->allocated_len = 512
msg->len = 0

Why this? Is there any other way to get interactive input from the user using glib functions?

I'll be grateful if somebody could help me!

Comment: I don't understand what you want, what kind of input do you want? And what is a GString (other than the guitar string)?

EDIT: I just looked it up, from what I understood you want to use standard ANSI C functions right? You can simply use scanf() to read from stdin.

Comment: @Ricardo Ferreira - There is at least one more common usage of g-string than a guitar. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the `do_fgets` is your own function wrapping `fgets`, anyway...

Your code is failing since it is trying to read 0 bytes (the initial value of `msg->len`). Additionally, `msg->len` is never updated (it is passed to `do_fgets` by value).

Comment: ok, let my clarify it; do_fgets is just like fgets() so forget it and let it be fgets() from now on. GString is a struct of glib.h as defined here:  http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Strings.html What I want is to read a string from the user and store it in GString->str. How can I initiate len member(shouldn't it happen automatically?). I understand that during allocation for GString in line 4, the allocated_len member is set to 512.

Comment: @xstop: it would happen automatically if you were using one of the `g_string_`* functions. since you are not, you should set the `len` member to the actual length of the string (not including the terminating nul byte). you can use `allocated_len` as the number of bytes to read, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Resurection!
I think I've found the solution to my question. What I did is to read the input to a buffer and then assign the buffer to the struct member src an everything is ok. That's the code roughly:

```
int main(void)
{
  GString *msg = NULL;
  gchar *p;
  gchar buf[256];
  msg = g_string_sized_new(256);
  printf ("Enter a message (255 characters at most): ");
  p = fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
  g_string_assign(msg, buf);
  printf("msg->str = [%s] \n", (char *) msg->str);
  printf("msg->len = %u \n", (size_t) msg->len);
  printf("msg->allocated_len = %u \n", (size_t) msg->allocated_len);
  return 0;
}
```

So it prints out:

```
msg->str = [this is my message] 
msg->len = 19 
msg->allocated_len = 512
```

The only strange is why the allocated_len is 512 instead of 256.
Thanks to everyone for the reply...

Comment: You should have used have posted another question. Anyway; GString expand at the rate of powers of 2. When you call g_string_sized_new(256) you indicate you want to pre-allocate enough space for 256 characters (internally: +1 for the \0 char it places at the end). Because of this 257 gets turned into the closest power of 2 (2^8->2^9), making the final allocated_len 512, the results you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Resurrection, debugging led me to the next solution. Thank you Hasturkun for your help, I wanted to post my answer since yesterday but new members cannot answer their questions before 8 hours pass. The solution is this:

```
int main(void)
{
  GString *msg = NULL;
  gchar *p;
  gchar buf[256];

  msg = g_string_sized_new(256);
  printf ("Enter a message (255 characters at most): ");
  p = fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
  g_string_assign(msg, buf);
  printf("msg->str = [%s] \n", (char *) msg->str);
  printf("msg->len = %u \n", (size_t) msg->len);
  printf("msg->allocated_len = %u \n", (size_t) msg->allocated_len);
}
```

And it prints out everything very well...
Thank you all for your comments!